# Clear multidimensional cookie in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I used multidimensional cookie to store a cookie in my application.
For example

```
HttpCookie MyCookie = Request.Cookies["Temp"] as HttpCookie;
                if (MyCookie != null)
                {
                    MyCookie.Values["SID"] = Session.SessionID;
                   MyCookie.Values["NAME"] = "NAME";
                   MyCookie.Values["abc"] = "abc";
                   MyCookie.Values["xyz"] = "xyz";
                   ...
                }
```

Now to retrieve this multidimensional cookie I used.

```
string s  = Request.Cookies["Temp"]["SID"]
```

My question is I want to expire only "SID" value from the "Temp" cookie. I tried with this

```
Request.Cookies["Temp"]["SID"] = null;
```

but it's not working. What should I do clear particular index from multidimensional cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered in the following question: [ASP.NET Cookie Sub-Value Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256388/asp-net-cookie-sub-value-deletion)

HttpCookie.Values is a NameValueCollection, so you can modify that collection - but you will need to re-send the cookie as a new one to overwrite the old one:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Temp"];
if(cookie != null)
{
    cookie.Values.Remove("SID");
    Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
}
```

This is also explained in the following MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor9

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
Request.Cookies["Temp"].Values["SID"] = null;
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This will not work too. You need to append the cookie back to Response